# I am trying to test using jest for a function that calls back a success message to be displayed once a task is added to array but its erroring out

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs

This is the code I have to so far. I need help with my test function using jest. Visual studio points error to function addTask("task 3) in the test function. The rest of the code executes fine i.e I am able to display a success message after adding task to the array. The test should pass this requirement of displaying success message only after adding the task to the array.

```
function successMessage(callback){
    callback("Task3");
    console.log('success')
}
var tasks=[];
tasks=[{task_content:"Task 1",status:"open"},
       {task_content:"Task 2",status:"closed"}];

//Function addTask adds specific task to tasks array
function addTask(add_task) {
    var status="open";
    var new_task={task_content:add_task,status:status};
    tasks.push(new_task);
    console.log("After adding on Task 3");
    console.log(tasks);
    
}
console.log("Initially Tasks array: ");
console.log(tasks);

successMessage(addTask)

test('success msg', done => {
    function addTask("task3"){
        try{
            expect("task 3").toEqual({task_content: 'task3', status: 'open'})
            done()
        }catch(error){
            done(error)
        }
    }
    successMessage(addTask);
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had converted the above problem into using a promise. I was able to produce the test case with simpler understanding upon using and returning the value of promise rather than callbacks. I am still a noob but this is what has been working for me so far.

```
var tasks=[];
tasks=[{task_content:"Task 1",status:"open"},
            {task_content:"Task 2",status:"closed"}];

function addTask(add_task) {
    
    var status="open";
    var new_task={task_content:add_task,status:status};
    tasks.push(new_task);
    console.log("After adding on Task 3");
    console.log(tasks);
                
    }
    function successMessage(){
        console.log('success')
    }
    function first(){
        var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        resolve(addTask('task 3'))
        })
        return promise1;
    }
    function second(){
        var promise2 = new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
                    //addTask("task 3")
        console.log('success')
        resolve(second)
                    
    })
    return promise2;
            
    }
            
    first();
    second();
    test('promise',()=>{
        return first().then(()=>{
            expect(second()).resolves.toBe('success')
        })
        //expect(first()).then(second()).resolves.toBe('success')
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

function addTask(add_task) {

```
var status="open";
var new_task={task_content:add_task,status:status};
tasks.push(new_task);
console.log("After adding on Task 3");
console.log(tasks);
            
}
function successMessage(){
    console.log('success')
}
function first(){
    var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
    resolve(addTask('task 3'))
    })
    return promise1;
}
function second(){
    var promise2 = new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
                //addTask("task 3")
    console.log('success')
    resolve(second)
                
})
return promise2;
        
}
        
first();
second();
test('promise',()=>{
    return first().then(successCall=>{
        expect(second()).resolves.toBe('success')
    })
})
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).